# Join MUC room to become occupants of MUC room via Ejabberd API

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I am working on sending message to muc room via API http. I observed that it s possible by `get_room_occupants` users who has joined muc room.

Now, from ejabberd muc room I have found that team members are there but are not occupants of the team, thats why is shows this error `Only occupants are allowed to send messages to the conference` though being group members.

Is there any api which can connect me to muc and show me in occupants?

Ejabberd Version : 17.11
Installed on : ubuntu 16.04
Configuered DB : mysql

Ejaberd.yml

```
api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who: all
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who: all
    what:
      - "*"
commands_admin_access:
  - allow:
    - user: "xxx@yy.zz"
commands:
  add_commands:
    - status
    - registered_users
    - register
    - unregister
    - get_roster
    - connected_users
    - send_stanza_c2s
    - send_stanza
    - join_cluster
oauth_expire: 3600
oauth_access: all
```

Comment: Can you share me the permissions of the group?

Comment: I have updated the question. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An account with admin rights in the MUC service can send messages to any room, no need to be room occupant.

For example, with this configuration:

```
acl:
  admin:
    user:
      - "user1@localhost"
modules:
  mod_muc:
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
```

I can execute this query, providing an account that exist and a room that exists, but that account is not occupant in that room:

```
$ ejabberdctl send_message groupchat user1@localhost room1@conference.localhost Sub Bodyyy
```

The occupants in that room receive the message:

```
<message to='user2@localhost/tka1'
    from='room1@conference.localhost'
    type='groupchat'
    id='1234779465623896577'>
  <body xml:lang='en'>Bodyyy</body>
  <subject xml:lang='en'>Sub</subject>
</message>
```

Alternatively, you can subscribe an account to a MUC room, and then that account is allowed to send messages to the room without being occupant. For example:

```
$ ejabberdctl subscribe_room user2@localhost/tka1 User2 room1@conference.localhost urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:messages
urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:messages

$ ejabberdctl send_message groupchat user2@localhost room1@conference.localhost Sub Bodyyy
```

Comment: message is sent successfully, but will it prompt users who are online? Because if I open room again message history is there. Not when connected to room

Comment: I am facing issue of "Subscriptions now allowed" issue with       db_type: sql
    default_room_options:
      - mam: true
      - allow_subscription: true
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    history_size: 100

Comment: See the example configuration in the ejabberd Guide, the default options go without - character, like this: `allow_subscription: true`. And those default options are applied to new rooms, not to the ones already existing.